CompletableFuture miss-understanding
I seem to fail miserably at an apparently simple example with CompletableFuture.
I have a CompletableFuture that is blocked in a different thread, something like:
        Supplier<CompletableFuture<String>> one = () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("started cf");
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));
            System.out.println("done cf");
            return "";
        });
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                future = one.get();
                future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("caught");
                future.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });

I want to be able to cancel it, and then join to wait until it is completed in a thread that is different then the one above, so something like this:
    static CompletableFuture<String> future;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Supplier<CompletableFuture<String>> one = () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("started cf");
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));
            System.out.println("done cf");
            return "";
        });
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                future = one.get();
                future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("caught");
                future.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });

        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        future.cancel(true);
        System.out.println("before join");
        String s = future.join();
        System.out.println("s value : " + s);
        System.out.println("done");
    }

To my surprise, this one String s = future.join(); blocks and I don't understand why.
More surprising, if I change my code to (instead of String s = future.join();):
        String s = null;
        try {
            s = future.join();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("here : " + e.getClass());
        }

this one does not block. Can someone please shed some light here?

I don't think you can join() on a cancelled thread.

@ElliottFrisch the thing I don't get is why it works then for when I add a try/catch block

I suggest you add a call to CompletableFuture#isCompletedExceptionally().

For what it’s worth, I would not call this a simple example.

Why do you have the future.completeExceptionally(e); in your code? This marks the future as completed and join()ing on a completed Future doesn't need to wait.

@Eugene I was a bit hesitant to close as duplicate but I think those questions should answer yours. It’s a bit complicated because your example isn’t exactly minimal. You could reduce it to basically future = supplyAsync(…, service), and remove the Supplier part and the service.submit() and observe the same effect(s). Then it boils down to 1) cancel() does not do what you think it does, and 2) what are the conditions for the JVM to terminate (also technically the join() call is not blocking in your example, it just throws an exception)

Your access to future is not thread safe. Besides that, I could not reproduce your issue. This code produced a CancellationException at the join() call in every run.

@Holger hmm, why is it not thread safe here? I seems to miss your point a bit. Can you please explain more?

You write to the future variable in a background thread but read it in the main thread which no precaution to make this exchange thread safe. I thought you knew about memory visibility etc.

@Holger ah! ok, thank you for the note. I did not realize that, indeed.

@DidierL thank you for closing it! I was trying to simplify and somehow make sense to myself of a more complicated issue that I was facing... In the end, you links helped a lot. i re-read them after a break and it all made sense.

With or without the try/catch around future.join() this blocks for me in the same way, whereby I define "blocking" here as: I put your code into a file, run it from the command line and the process does not finish.
The reason is that Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() works with a non-daemon thread, meaning the pool's thread keeps on running even when the main() method returns (you should see your "done" output). Consequently the program's process does not finish.
You may either

call service.shutdown() or some of its variants before future.join() or
use the variant newSingleThreadExecutor(ThreadFactory) where the thread factory provides a daemon thread (.setDaemon(true))

